# Possible to externally access Sharepoint 2013 via Javascript alone?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to access SharePoint List Data from an external javascript sitting outside the SharePoint environment? Is there an example out there?

Comment: Are you using SharePoint on-premises or SharePoint Online?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint has WebService as well as REST end points.

You can access these using JavaScript AJAX. The biggest hurdle you will encounter will be with Authentication and Cross Domain service calls.

Comment: Really a true & awesome answer.